# xml to datatable

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

Having trouble with importing the xml to a datatable than view it in listview.

```
<Players>
  <Player>
    <Name>Joe</Name>
    <Kills>352</Kills>
    <Death>608</Death>
  </Player>
  <Player>
    <Name>^1dR.eViL</Name>
    <Kills>8224</Kills>
    <Death>4592</Death>
  </Player>
<Players>
```

Now to get the table I did the following:

```
public DataTable getTable()
{
    string file = @"E:\...\Players.xml";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(file);
    return ds.Tables["Players"];

}
```

To generate the list view I did the following:

```
public void generateScoreBoard(DataTable dt)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row[0].ToString());
                for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    item.SubItems.Add(row[i].ToString());
                }
                lvScoreBoard.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

It seems to me that having one level higher misses up with the data being input in the datatable and that not specifying columns before hand makes it so it doesn't create columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what your question is, but looking at your code, your problem may be due to the fact that your getTable() method will never return a DataTable named "Players" (note the plural) - "Players" is the name of the DataSet and "Player" is the name of the DataTable.

If you change the name of the returned DataTable from "Players" to "Player", you should be good.

Example:

```
public DataTable getTable()
{
    string file = @"E:\...\Players.xml";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(file);
    return ds.Tables["Player"]; // The name of the table in the dataset is "Player"

}
```

Comment: Yup, I actually figured that out a while back but what threw me off is the listview displays it really bad .... so i switch to a grid view.
You got the write answer though so You win ! :P

Answer (score 1):

If you get to decide the formatting of the XML, the easiest way is to create a DataTable with some data first and export it to XML.  Then you'll have the format that you can read back in.

I do that [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2009/01/05/create-an-xsd-schema-without-knowing-a-damn-thing-about-xsd.aspx)

Comment: 2 inconvenience: is that whenever new columns of data would be added, the person would have to come and add them manually. Also, for 2-3 lines of conversation from xml to datatable to be 10x times more is not really welcoming.

Comment: It is just to show you what XML format the DataTable 'likes' so you can use the minimum effort possible reading XML with a DataTable.

Comment: Yeah, actually I read it and found most interesting. Thanks. +1